# Android App RecyclerView Crash Issue with Different JSON Structures

Tags: java, android, json, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

I'm encountering a problem in my Android app where I retrieve data from different JSON endpoints. The app works well when fetching data from [URL 1], but when I switch to [URL 2], the app crashes, and I see an "onFailure" toast.

I've noticed that the JSON structures from the two endpoints are different. The first JSON structure (URL 1) is similar to:

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Title_1",
      "cat": "Comedy"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Title_2",
      "cat": "Animation"
    }
    // ... other category items
  ]
}
```

While the second JSON structure (URL 2) looks like:

```json
{
  "films": {
    "Film1": {
      "title": "Film1",
      // ... other film details
    },
    // ... other films
  },
  "categories": {
    "Comedy": ["Film1", "Film2", "Film3"],
    // ... other category mappings
  }
}
```

I suspect the issue might be related to how I handle these different JSON structures in my RecyclerView and adapters.

Could you please guide me on how to adapt my RecyclerView, models, and adapters to handle these varying JSON structures correctly? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Model and adapter classes and...

Models:

```java
public class CategoryResponse {

    @SerializedName("categories")
    private ArrayList<CategoryItem> items_cat;

    @SerializedName("films")
    private ArrayList<CategoryItem> items_films;

    // Getter and Setter...
}
```

```
public class CategoryItem {

    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;

    @SerializedName("cat")
    private String category;

    @SerializedName("title")
    private String title;

// Getter ans setter
   
}
```

API - interface:

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("{add}")
    Call<CategoryResponse> get_Api(@Path("add") String addUrl);

}
```

Retrofit2:

```
public class ApiClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit;

    public static Retrofit getRetrofitItem(String BASE_URL) {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.CategoryViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    private ArrayList<CategoryItem> categoryItems;

    public CategoryAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CategoryItem> categoryItems) {
        this.context = context;
        this.categoryItems = categoryItems;
    }

    //....

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CategoryViewHolder holder, int position) {

        String category = categoryItems.get(position).getCategory();
        holder.categoryName.setText(category);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return categoryItems.size();
    }

    public static class CategoryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView categoryName;

        public CategoryViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            categoryName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_title);
        }
    }
}
```

and Activity Class:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityHomeBinding binding;

    private String BaseURL = "https://xxxxxxx.com/xx/"; // Site Address
    private String addURL = "xx.json";

    private CategoryAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityHomeBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());


        loadJson(BaseURL, addURL);

    }

    private void loadJson(String url, String addURL) {

        ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient
                .getRetrofitItem(url).create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<CategoryResponse> listCall = apiInterface.get_Api(addURL);

        listCall.enqueue(new Callback<CategoryResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<CategoryResponse> call,
                                   @NonNull Response<CategoryResponse> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        GenerateList(response.body().getItems_cat());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<CategoryResponse> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
              // "onFailure" toast.
            }
        });

    }

    private void GenerateList(ArrayList<CategoryItem> items) {
        adapter = new CategoryAdapter(this, items);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        binding.recycleItem.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        binding.recycleItem.setHasFixedSize(true);

        binding.recycleItem.setAdapter(adapter);
        binding.recycleItem.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
    }

}
```

Please tell me in which sections I should make changes.
To run the program with the second structure [URL 2], and the program does not crash .

Thank you.

The app works well when fetching data from [URL 1], but when I switch to [URL 2], the app crashes, and I see an "onFailure" toast.

Comment: Print out the exception message in `onFailure` to see what the actual error is? In Json1 "categories" is an array, but in the other scheme it is a JSONObject, as is "films", but your `CategoryResponse` is looking for arrays for both.

Comment: Your model classes are defined to match the JSON structure of the response from URL 1. You can't reasonably expect to change the JSON structure and have it continue to work. Update your model classes to match the new JSON structure.